# How to configure a polygon on a tkinter canvas using a class?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is my current working code but I want to add in a function that will change the color of the shape during 'mainloop':

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()

class GUI(Canvas):
    '''inherits Canvas class (all Canvas methodes, attributes will be accessible)
   You can add your customized methods here.
   '''
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master=master, *args, **kwargs)

polygon = GUI(root)
polygon.create_polygon([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150],     outline='gray', 
        fill='gray', width=2)

polygon.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I was thinking something like this would work (inside the class):

```
def configure(self,colour):
    Canvas.itemconfig(self,fill=colour)
```

Then I call it with:

```
polygon.configure('red')
```

But I keep getting this error and I dont know how to fix it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
File "C:/Users/User/Documents/Algies homework/Hexaheaflexagon sim.py", line 117, in configure
Canvas.itemconfig(self,fill=colour)
TypeError: itemconfigure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tagOrId'
```

Comment: Obviously this is homework.  I think the intent is to create a polygon within the class, and a method/function to change the color, also within the class (and the class has to know about a reference to the polygon object to change the color).  You also have to create an instance of the class.  See this link for starter info and the calculateArea() functions are representative of how you would change the color http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutclass.htm

Comment: It is homework but no you are wrong, I'm making a hexahexaflexagon simulator, I already have working classes and code for the actual nodes and transitions as well as other widgets and the set up for the GUI, cheers for the link :) looks hopeful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you try to do this

```
from Tkinter import*

# --- class ---

class GUI(Canvas):
    '''inherits Canvas class (all Canvas methodes, attributes will be accessible)
   You can add your customized methods here.
   '''
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master=master, *args, **kwargs)
        # default - poly not exists
        self.poly = None

    def create_poly(self, points, outline='gray', fill='gray', width=2):
        # remember poly
        self.poly = self.create_polygon(points, outline=outline, fill=fill, width=width)

    def set_poly_fill(self, color):
        # if poly exists then you can change fill
        if self.poly:
            self.itemconfig(self.poly, fill=color)

# --- main ---

root = Tk()

polygon = GUI(root)
polygon.create_poly([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150])
polygon.set_poly_fill('red')
polygon.pack()

root.mainloop()
```